# ElastAlert : multiple query against multiple indices in same rule file

Tags: elastalert

I have created 2 separate rule files , which are as follows:-

realert:
  minutes: 5
from_addr: test@email.com
es_host: xx.xx.xxx.xx
index: topbeat-*
smtp_host: ismtp.corp.company.com
type: frequency
es_port: 9200
filter:
 - range:
    mem.used_p:
      from: 0.70
      to: 1.0
 - term:
    beat.hostname: xxxxx
timeframe:
  minutes: 30
alert: email
name: 9__server__xxxxx__mem.used_p__0.70__30
email: ["user@email.com"]
num_events: 1

realert:
  minutes: 5
from_addr: test@email.com
es_host: xx.xx.xxx.xx
index: packetbeat-*
smtp_host: ismtp.corp.company.com
type: frequency
es_port: 9200
filter:
 - term:
    http.code: 404
 - term:
    beat.hostname: yyyyy
timeframe:
  minutes: 30
alert: email
name: 25__app__yyyyy__http.code__404__1__30
email: ["user@email.com"]
num_events: 1

Both rule files are generating emails as per their definition.

Is there any way to have these two rule files as a single rule file.
where I might need to define, index:topbeat-,packetbeat-
Then in that case how I need to write filters, so that mem.used_p is queried against topbeat-* for server xxxxx and http.code is queried against packetbeat-* for server yyyyy. ???